# New question or edit existing question with new sample code?

Tags: discussion, edits

I had a look at some similar questions here on Meta:

- [Should I ask a new question, or edit the existing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108734/should-i-ask-a-new-question-or-edit-the-existing)
- [Edit code or post new question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103517/edit-code-or-post-new-question)

...but they don't really fit the problem I have, which is the following:

I [asked a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377243/eclipse-console-lines-missing-from-the-end), which hasn't attracted any answers yet, just some comments. [Based on a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/21733714?noredirect=1), the code sample I posted to replicate the problem doesn't seem to be very effective.

Now, by accident, I found another, shorter code sample which seems to be more effective to reproduce the problem and therefore I'm wondering if I should edit the existing question or start a new one with the new code sample?

Comment: Since there are no active answers on the post yet, you won't risk getting anyone angry for their efforts being wasted. If problem is still the same, editing the same question should serve the purpose here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're refining your original question, and you still have the same problem, you should simply edit.

Unless your entire problem scenario has changed, your original question is trying to solve the same problem you still have.